# Aggregate vs Sum Performance in LINQ

Tags: c#, performance, linq, sum, aggregate

Three different implementations of finding the sum of an **IEnumerable < int> source** are given below along with the time taken when the source has 10,000 integers.

```
source.Aggregate(0, (result, element) => result + element);
```

takes 3 ms

```
source.Sum(c => c);
```

takes 12 ms

```
source.Sum();
```

takes 1 ms

I am wondering why the second implementation is four times more expensive than the first one. Shouldn't it be same as the third implementation.

Comment: What are your test conditions ?

Comment: how did you get these times? How many time did you try the results?

Comment: I profiled it using dotTrace. I ran it once, but the three runs are independent.

Comment: try to run each test in a loop, this remove all the times taken for jitting and so on, the test will be more accurate.

Comment: The results remain same after couple of runs also.

Comment: Are you running this under x86 or x64? Can you try the other one?

Answer (score 89, accepted):

Note: My computer is running .Net 4.5 RC, so it's possible that my results are affected by this.

Measuring the time it takes to execute a method just once is usually not very useful. It can be easily dominated by things like JIT compilation, which are not actual bottlenecks in real code. Because of this, I measured executing each method 100× (in Release mode without debugger attached). My results are:

- `Aggregate()`: 9 ms
- `Sum(lambda)`: 12 ms
- `Sum()`: 6 ms

The fact that `Sum()` is the fastest is not surprising: it contains a simple loop without any delegate invocations, which is really fast. The difference between `Sum(lambda)` and `Aggregate()` is not nearly as prominent as what you measured, but it's still there. What could be the reason for it? Let's look at decompiled code for the two methods:

```
public static TAccumulate Aggregate<TSource, TAccumulate>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, TAccumulate seed, Func<TAccumulate, TSource, TAccumulate> func)
{
    if (source == null)
        throw Error.ArgumentNull("source");
    if (func == null)
        throw Error.ArgumentNull("func");

    TAccumulate local = seed;
    foreach (TSource local2 in source)
        local = func(local, local2);
    return local;
}

public static int Sum<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, int> selector)
{
    return source.Select<TSource, int>(selector).Sum();
}
```

As you can see, `Aggregate()` uses a loop but `Sum(lambda)` uses `Select()`, which in turn uses an iterator. And using an iterator means there is some overhead: creating the iterator object and (probably more importantly) one more method invocation for each item.

Let's verify that using `Select()` is actually the reason by writing our own `Sum(lambda)` twice, once using `Select()`, which should behave the same as `Sum(lambda)` from the framework, and once without using `Select()`:

```
public static int SlowSum<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, int> selector)
{
    return source.Select(selector).Sum();
}

public static int FastSum<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, int> selector)
{
    if (source == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("source");
    if (selector == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("selector");

    int num = 0;
    foreach (T item in source)
        num += selector(item);
    return num;
}
```

My measurements confirm what I thought:

- `SlowSum(lambda)`: 12 ms
- `FastSum(lambda)`: 9 ms

Comment: Very insightful. Thanks for the detailed response.

Comment: This is one of the best answers I've seen on SO, perfectly explained and well crafted. (+1 obviously)

Comment: foreach will also create an iterator so I don't think this explanation is correct.

Comment: @kjbartel I believe what I meant is that it creates an *additional* iterator. With `Aggregate()`, there is only the iterator used by `foreach`. But with this implementation of `Sum(lambda)`, there is one iterator used by `Select` and one used by `Sum()`.

Answer (score 1):

Only a decade late, but...

I've worked on a Linq replacement ([nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Cistern.ValueLinq), [github](https://github.com/manofstick/Cistern.ValueLinq)), which is (mostly!) a drop in replacement for System.Linq (just by adding the nuget package and then changing `using System.Linq` to `using Cistern.ValueLinq`) but using value types and some tricks under the hood.

Anyway, as far as `Sum` goes, it uses SIMD instructions under the hood (still honouring overflow) where it can.

Results below are running on a machine which is old as this original stackoverflow question, so modern machines should even have better results (although for a non SIMD able IEnumerable you do are getting some overhead)

```cs
public enum ContainerTypes { Enumerable, Array, List, }

[MemoryDiagnoser]
public class Benchmarks
{
    IEnumerable<int> _data;

    [Params(ContainerTypes.Array, ContainerTypes.Enumerable, ContainerTypes.List)]
    public ContainerTypes ContainerType { get; set; } = ContainerTypes.Enumerable;

    [GlobalSetup]
    public void SetupData()
    {
        var data = System.Linq.Enumerable.Range(0, 1000);
        _data = ContainerType switch
        {
            ContainerTypes.Enumerable => data,
            ContainerTypes.Array => System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray(data),
            ContainerTypes.List => System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList(data),
            _ => throw new Exception("Unknown ContainerType")
        };
    }

    [Benchmark(Baseline = true)] public int System_Linq_Sum() => System.Linq.Enumerable.Sum(_data);
    [Benchmark] public int System_Linq_Sum_Predicate() => System.Linq.Enumerable.Sum(_data, c => c);
    [Benchmark] public int System_Linq_Aggregate() => System.Linq.Enumerable.Aggregate(_data, 0, (result, element) => result + element);
    [Benchmark] public int Cistern_ValueLinq_Sum() => Cistern.ValueLinq.Enumerable.Sum(_data);
    [Benchmark] public int Cistern_ValueLinq_Sum_Predicate() => Cistern.ValueLinq.Enumerable.Sum(_data, c => c);
    [Benchmark] public int Cistern_ValueLinq_Aggregate() => Cistern.ValueLinq.Enumerable.Aggregate(_data, 0, (result, element) => result + element);

    static void Main(string[] args) => BenchmarkRunner.Run<Benchmarks>();
}
```

| Method | ContainerType | Mean | Error | StdDev | Median | Ratio | RatioSD | Gen 0 | Gen 1 | Gen 2 | Allocated |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| System_Linq_Sum | Enumerable | 6.025 us | 0.1155 us | 0.1501 us | 6.041 us | 1.00 | 0.00 | 0.0076 | - | - | 40 B |
| System_Linq_Sum_Predicate | Enumerable | 8.731 us | 0.1727 us | 0.3681 us | 8.742 us | 1.45 | 0.08 | - | - | - | 40 B |
| System_Linq_Aggregate | Enumerable | 8.534 us | 0.1683 us | 0.3514 us | 8.657 us | 1.42 | 0.07 | - | - | - | 40 B |
| Cistern_ValueLinq_Sum | Enumerable | 6.907 us | 0.1369 us | 0.3061 us | 6.911 us | 1.15 | 0.07 | 0.0076 | - | - | 40 B |
| Cistern_ValueLinq_Sum_Predicate | Enumerable | 9.769 us | 0.1907 us | 0.1784 us | 9.823 us | 1.62 | 0.04 | - | - | - | 40 B |
| Cistern_ValueLinq_Aggregate | Enumerable | 9.295 us | 0.1847 us | 0.4962 us | 9.396 us | 1.52 | 0.08 | - | - | - | 40 B |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| System_Linq_Sum | Array | 6.731 us | 0.1343 us | 0.3653 us | 6.814 us | 1.00 | 0.00 | 0.0076 | - | - | 32 B |
| System_Linq_Sum_Predicate | Array | 9.432 us | 0.1873 us | 0.5065 us | 9.685 us | 1.41 | 0.11 | - | - | - | 32 B |
| System_Linq_Aggregate | Array | 9.494 us | 0.1890 us | 0.4707 us | 9.759 us | 1.41 | 0.11 | - | - | - | 32 B |
| Cistern_ValueLinq_Sum | Array | 1.404 us | 0.0279 us | 0.0710 us | 1.436 us | 0.21 | 0.02 | - | - | - | - |
| Cistern_ValueLinq_Sum_Predicate | Array | 4.064 us | 0.0811 us | 0.0996 us | 4.087 us | 0.61 | 0.04 | - | - | - | - |
| Cistern_ValueLinq_Aggregate | Array | 3.549 us | 0.0709 us | 0.1496 us | 3.584 us | 0.53 | 0.04 | - | - | - | - |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| System_Linq_Sum | List | 11.779 us | 0.2344 us | 0.3048 us | 11.854 us | 1.00 | 0.00 | - | - | - | 40 B |
| System_Linq_Sum_Predicate | List | 14.227 us | 0.2842 us | 0.6919 us | 14.601 us | 1.22 | 0.05 | - | - | - | 40 B |
| System_Linq_Aggregate | List | 13.852 us | 0.2761 us | 0.7418 us | 14.249 us | 1.17 | 0.06 | - | - | - | 40 B |
| Cistern_ValueLinq_Sum | List | 1.437 us | 0.0288 us | 0.0835 us | 1.471 us | 0.12 | 0.01 | - | - | - | - |
| Cistern_ValueLinq_Sum_Predicate | List | 3.672 us | 0.0732 us | 0.1941 us | 3.771 us | 0.32 | 0.02 | - | - | - | - |
| Cistern_ValueLinq_Aggregate | List | 3.597 us | 0.0718 us | 0.1880 us | 3.698 us | 0.31 | 0.02 | - | - | - | - |

Comment: Are you using the [Vector.IsHardwareAccelerated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.vector.ishardwareaccelerated) property, to avoid using SIMD when not available?

Comment: It is used https://github.com/manofstick/Cistern.ValueLinq/blob/6afdd2f0031c06bbb3ac170910311995210ccb18/ValueLinq/Maths/SIMD.cs#L214 are you saying that it doesn't work properly?

Comment: No, AFAIK it works correctly. I am just wondering whether you query this property in order to fall back to normal LINQ operators, in case the current machine does not support SIMD. Because in that case the SIMD operations are simulated, and the performance suffers.